# Is clang supporting llvm 2.6?

Tags: llvm, clang

all. I am trying to use llvm-2.6 with clang-3.4 since I could not find clang for llvm-2.6.
Is clang-3.4 supporting llvm-2.6? Are there any issues known so far?
Any comments would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is No.

The longer answer is: LLVM and Clang are being developed in-sync, and it's almost never possible to fully connect Clang version X to LLVM version Y with X != Y. The farther apart X and Y are, the harder it is. For 2.6/3.4 it's impossible - the LLVM IR has underwent many major changes since 2.6, and Clang 3.4 will generate IR that's unintelligible to LLVM 2.6

Why do you need to use LLVM 2.6 is the real question.

Comment: Actually I want to use sub-project implemented based on LLVM 2.6. Anyway, thanks.